# Web API 'Request' is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return an `HttpResponseException` from a POST Web API action using 'Request':

```
throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not in a correct size"));
```

When doing so, I get `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: request`.

Essentially - **Request** is null.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: to confirm try using `throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)`

Comment: Hi Rwiti, you're suggestion did work as well as the following:

`throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent("Invalid size"),
                        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
                    });`

However on client side (JS) I could not get a hold of 'Content' property.. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
message.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(MessageResponse), "Invalid Size", GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
throw new HttpResponseException(message);
```

Note: you can change "Invalid Size" with any object you may want to return for the user.
e.g.:

```
public ErrorMessage
{
     public string Error;
     public int ErrorCode;
}

ErrorMessage msg = new ErrorMessage();
msg.Error = "Invalid Size";
msg.ErrorCode = 500;

HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
message.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(MessageResponse), msg, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
throw new HttpResponseException(message);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is correct and does work however I would still like to know why 'Request' is null in that context.

Comment: @Leo did you find the answer why Request is null in Web API controller?

Answer (score 6):

I found that my Request object was null within my ApiController because I have nested one ApiController call within another. The second, nested ApiController was therefore never initialized. You can't initialize it manually, but you can leverage the setter on the Request object to pass from wrapper to nested ApiController. A mockup is below, in my real code it fixed my Request.CreateErrorResponse(...) error.

```
public class WrapperController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/wrapper
    public void Post(ComplexWithChild value)
    {
        var other = value.otherdata;

        var childcontroller = new ChildController();
        childcontroller.Post(value.child); // ChildController is not initialized, and has null Request
        /*inside ChildController...// causes null reference exception due to null Request
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "my message"); 
        */

        childcontroller.Request = this.Request;
        childcontroller.Post(value.child); // ChildController uses same Request
        /*inside ChildController...// this works now
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "my message"); 
        */
    }
}

public class ChildController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(Child value)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "my message"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This code may only have worked in Web Api 1, I believe it does not work in Asp.Net Web Api 2

Comment: I got `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The request context property on the request must be null or match ApiController.RequestContext.'`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for people like @DavB.cs who have nested ApiControllers like:

```
public class ParentController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Foo()
    {
       ChildRepository.Foo();
       return Ok(...);
    }
}

public class ChildRepository : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Foo()
    {
        // Do something
        return Request.CreateResponse(...);
    }
}
```

Is simply to just pass in Request from the ParentController as such:

```
public class ParentController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Foo()
        {
           ChildRepository.Foo(Request);
           return Ok(...);
        }
    }

    public class ChildRepository
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Foo(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            // Do something
            return request.CreateResponse(...);
        }
    }
```

Request comes from ApiController. This will get you past the 'Request is null' issue.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Of all the suggested solutions (which I have also used), this was my favorite, thanks Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

nizari's answer is correct however I ended up using the following:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent("Invalid image dimensions. Image file must be " + image.Width + "x" + image.Height + "px"),
                        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
                    });
```

and accessing the content on client side using `jqXHR.responseText`

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on nizari's answer, Here's what I did in order to include a list of ErrorMessage objects:

```
IEnumerable errorList = new List<ErrorMessage>();

// ...

var error = new HttpError( "There were errors." ) 
{
    { "Errors", errorList }
};

var message = new HttpResponseMessage( HttpStatusCode.BadRequest )
{
    Content = new ObjectContent<HttpError>( error, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter )
};

throw new HttpResponseException( message );
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new instance of the System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage. the below would work

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
var response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not in a correct size");

throw new HttpResponseException(response);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpResponseMessage message = new  HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError); 
message.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(MessageResponse),
                                    "Invalid Size",
                                    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter); 
throw new HttpResponseException(message);
```